# Appropritely dropping Box copied from pointer in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust

I have a very simple snippet

```rust
let a = Box::new(100);
let b = unsafe { ptr::read(&a) };
```

On exit, memory must be freed; thus the two boxes are dropped, but they point to the same memory location leading to an error

```
sm2-be78471d87150ecc(39668,0x7000075d5000) malloc: *** error for object 0x6000025e0000: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

What is the correct way to approach this case?

For example, I found the following options

```rust
let a = Box::new(100);
let b = ManuallyDrop::new(unsafe { ptr::read(&a) });
```

although, it seems it leaks memory by not dropping the second `Box` itself, or

```rust
let a = Box::new(100);
let b = unsafe { ptr::read(&a) };
mem::forget(b);
```

which seems to do what I want "This function consumes the value it is passed and then doesn't run its destructor."

Comment: Why do you think it leaks memory?

Comment: These two options are essentially the same (due to the definition of `mem::forget`), with the only difference that `ManuallyDrop` one is generally less error-prone.

Comment: Note that Miri reports this as undefined behaviour as soon as you try to read both boxes: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d481d51bf809d726bd4be6afc6e631ba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ManuallyDrop` is the correct way to do that. It does not leak any memory.

**However**, it is not clear that what you're doing is allowed at all. Put it differently - currently it is UB. It is UB to have two `Box`es pointing to the same memory, because `Box` has uniqueness guarantee, similar to `&mut` references. [Whether this is what we want is questionable](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326), but this is currently the case.

Instead, convert the `Box` to raw pointer with [`Box::into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw), then free it with [`Box::from_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) when you don't need it anymore.